# Uninstall Redistributable library when uninstalling My application Installshield2015 professional

Tags: prerequisites, redistributable, installshield-2015

I am installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.23026 as a prerequisite with my application. When I uninstall my application, the prerequisites should also get uninstalled silently.

Please let me know how can I achieve this. I have tried some ways searching on the internet, but they did not work.
I believe there might be a very simple and straight forward way to do so, I am the newbie to installshield so unable to catch it.

Any comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: Normally redist installs are left on the system when your product is uninstalled. I think you can uninstall if you add an action after InstallFinalize to uninstall the redist using
msiexec /x {<RedistProductCode>}

Comment: thanks @ David Daugherty i have tried this, but as we can not uninstall two applications at the same time (as other app is using the installer) so i have not find a way yet. i tried to explore chained msi approach, but my setup file and Redistributable file has extension of .exe, not .msi .

Comment: If you schedule it after InstallFinalize you should be able to. You can not run another install process between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize.

So if your redist is an exe you can look up the ProductCode it uses and launch the uninstall with it as listed above

Comment: thanks @ David Daugherty it works for me, previously i am calling it synchronously by checking the exit code and it was failing. Now i tried asynchronously without waiting and its working now but now  issue is : it is coming up at the time of installation also(after installation of my application is done), however i can use it to install the redistributables just running redis. exe, but i am not able to give cmd line arguments for silent install/uninstallation. (as at the time of installation i want to give /install /silent and at the time of uninstall i want to give /uninstall /silent.)

Comment: Sorry man i have replied without researching i am able to do so by adding a condition flag REMOVE`="ALL", thanks a lot for help David